# TSQL: how to write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which returns a result set which looks like this:

```
A   |   B
---------------------
1   |   a
2   |   a
1   |   b
1   |   c
3   |   d
```

`A|B` is unique in the results (i.e. there will only ever be one `1|a` row)

I need to write two queries based on these results. The first:

given a value for `A` (say `1`), count the number of `B`s who only have a single row; with a `1` in the `A` column.

so in the above data set, id expect to be returned the value **`2`**, because `B` values `b` and `c` only have one row each, where those rows have a `1` in the `A` column. `d` would not be counted because it corresponds to a `3` and `a` would not be returned because it has an additional row with a `2`.

Hope that makes sense.

The second query is the opposite to the above.

Given a value for `A` (say `1`) count the number of `B`s who have 2 or more rows, where one of the rows has a `1` in the `A` column.

So in the above data id expect to be returned **`1`**, because the `B` value `a` is the only one that has multiple rows, with one of them with a `1` in the A column.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CTEs and windowed aggregate functions, it could be done like this:

```
WITH
  sampledata (A, B) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'c' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'd'
  ),
  counted AS (
    SELECT
      A,
      B,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY B) B_count
    FROM sampledata
  )
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM counted
WHERE A = 1
  AND B_count = 1  /* change to "> 1" to get the other result */
```

Comment: how does this compare to Kirills answers with regards efficiency?, ive got a buttload of rows (100s of thousands)

Comment: @AndrewBullock: What Kirill said, I guess. Semi-joins (in the form of EXISTS predicates) are often hard to beat, and all the harder with a query that has got grouping (which implies sorting, which is costly). So yes, if your tables are that big, I would probably go with Kirill's solutions.

Comment: where A and B are uniqueidentifiers, this query runs in a second where as Kirills still hasnt returned in under a minute :s

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
declare @t table(A int, B char(1))

insert @t values
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(1, 'c'),
(3, 'd')

declare @x int = 1

select COUNT(*)
from @t t
where t.A = @x
    and not exists(select 1 from @t t2 where t2.B = t.B and t2.A <> @x)

select COUNT(*)
from @t t
where t.A = @x
    and exists(select 1 from @t t2 where t2.B = t.B and t2.A <> @x)
```

Queries provide exactly wanted result:

```
-----------
2    

-----------
1
```